# How can I initialize class or title in string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Variables pass, time and place are inputs from HTML, so when I click on button I am appending new row in the table, but every new row appended need to have different class and title, and that should be get from place input i.e. place.val().

```
$("button").click(function() {

   var pass = $("#pass");
   var time = $("#time");
   var place = $("#place");

   $("table").append("<tr><td>" + pass.val() + "</td><td>" + time.val() +
 "</td>" + "<td title=place.val() class=place.val()>" + 2 + "</td></tr>");

});
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) Could you create a code snippet or jsfiddle? Please include your HTML too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("button").click(function() {

   var pass = $("#pass");
   var time = $("#time");
   var place = $("#place");

   $("table").append("<tr><td>" + pass.val() + "</td><td>" + time.val() +
 "</td>" + "<td title=" + place.val() + " class=" + place.val() + ">" + 2 + "</td></tr>");

});
```